# OpenERP : how to add access to module installed in menu bar

Tags: menubar, openerp-7

I'm new in OpenERP and I need helping,

After installing any module, I does not find his name appears in the menu bar!, so how can I access it?

Comment: can you please specify the module,,? so that viewer can help you

Comment: any module, I want it to appear in the menu that I want to have access to use it exemple : eInvoicing & Payments or module that I will create it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't see the option menu to access to the required module content, may be it's because you don't have enough permissions to do it.

Go to *Configuration > Users*, select your user, go to the *Access Rights* tab and check that you are Responsible or Manager of the required module.

If you can't see the tab, you'll have to log in as the administrator of OpenERP and repeat the process I've wrote above.